# REQUEST Twitter timeline for username using Twitter API 1.1

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I am trying to request and parse 20 tweets from a given username using the code I have below. Although, in the NSLog, all I get is Bad Authentication Error. Can someone help me fix my code and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)getTweets:(NSString *)username {

    NSURL *getTimeline = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

    NSString *paraString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paraString forKey:@"username"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:getTimeline parameters:parameters];

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (granted) {
            NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if (accounts.count > 0)
            {
                for (ACAccount *twitterAccount in accounts) {
                    [request setAccount:twitterAccount];

                }
            }

            [self getTweets:@"@IsaRanjha"];
        }
    }
      ];

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
             NSLog(@"%@", json);

         }
         else
         {
             //Deal with error
         }


     }];}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your performRequestWithHandler is firing before you are granted access.  Add it to the requestAccessToAccountsWithType completion block like this.  You also shouldn't need to call the same function [self getTweets:@"@IsaRanjha"] from within itself.  Try it in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)getTweets:(NSString *)username {

    NSURL *getTimeline = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

    NSString *paraString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paraString forKey:@"seansamocki"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:getTimeline parameters:parameters];

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (granted) {
            NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if (accounts.count > 0)
            {
                for (ACAccount *twitterAccount in accounts) {
                    [request setAccount:twitterAccount];

                }
            }
                [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                {
                    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"%@", json);

                }
                else
                {
                    //Deal with error
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still getting Bad Authentication Error.

Comment: It worked for me/my username.  Try calling [self getTweets:@"IsaRanjha"] (without the second @).  Make sure that's your actual username.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home. What exactly does it report in the log, just the last 50 tweets right? And how would I load this info into a UITableView? Cause all I know is loading a UITableView with an array, could you also help me there? Thanks.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. Same error.   errors =     (
                {
            code = 215;
            message = "Bad Authentication data";
        }
    );
}

Comment: Is this account added to your iOS device/simulator in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Well Try this

```
-(void)getTweets
{

        ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
            if (granted) {

                NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                if (accounts.count > 0)
                {
                    ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

                    // Creating a request to get the info about a user on Twitter

                    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
                    NSDictionary* params = @{@"count" : @"50", @"screen_name" : @"IsaRanjha"};

                    SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                                       requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                                                 URL:url parameters:params];
                    [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
                    [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                            if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                                NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                                return;
                            }
                            if (error) {
                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                return;
                            }
                            if (responseData) {
                                NSError *jsonError;
                                self.twitterFeedsArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                          error:&jsonError];
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    NSLog(@"%@",@"Do");
                                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:TwitterGotPepsiTweets object:nil];
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }];
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No access granted");
            }
        }];
}
```

See how i pass the params for the api

```
NSDictionary* params = @{@"count" : @"50", @"screen_name" : @"IsaRanjha"};
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I run, not getting anything.

Comment: ok a quick look revealed that the twitter api workes only if you have the twitter app logged in with a valid account